# Ubuntu lags when copying big files from external disk

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive, copy

I have a dual boot system(Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on ASUS K556UQ-K).
When I copy a big file from windows partition or from an external hard drive to ubuntu, ubuntu lags.
Or for example when I work with anaconda in ubuntu and want to read a big CSV file and work with it, ubuntu lags.
And sometimes this happens when watching videos on youtube in ubuntu.
These happen only in ubuntu and windows is good.
I have checked for bad sectors and there's no bad sector in the hard-drive of my laptop.
And also when I check 'top' command in ubuntu when copying big files, everything is OK.
Do you have any idea, where is the problem from?

Comment: "Ubuntu lags when copying big files from external disk" so does windows. Software can never overcome hardware limitations. MS often decides to hide something from a user. The time it actually takes to copy is likely the same on both OS. "I have checked for bad sectors and there's no bad sector in the hard-drive of my laptop" Those do not affect the speed of copying a file as much as the version of USB, the cable used or activities done during that copy Mind also that it is possible to method of copying is not identical. If you use a tool that does verification the time to finish will be more.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for your comment. You said that MS hides something from user, but when I watch video on youtube, windows doesn't lag but ubuntu lags. If this is something related to hardware, how can MS hide the lags on youtube? I think the problem is related to somewhere else but I'm not sure.